# EF Core 6 - Remove column from SQL table without updating C# Model

Tags: c#, ef-core-6.0

I have a specific EF Core 6.x question.

If the SQL table has a column removed. Then EF Core will throw a SqlException saying that it's an invalid column name unless I also update the C# model.

For example,

```
Create Table User
(
   FirstName varchar(200)
  ,MiddleName varchar(200) null -- tried to remove this column after table is created
  ,LastName varchar(200)
)
```

I tried deleting the MiddleName column from the SQL Table.  When I run a simple read call using EF Core 6, I get the error.

c# model

```
public class User
{
   public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
   public virtual string? MiddleName { get; set; }
   public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}


var db = new EFDbContext(connectionString);
var data = db.Users.ToList();  // SqlException here after column removal
```

Is there any way to remove columns from the table without needing to update the c# class as well?

Tried making the C# property MiddleName not virtual.

**Update:**

In the event that I have an existing application.  I would need to modify the c# model even if the codebase doesn't refer to the removed column anywhere.  Alternatively, I can decorate the property with [NotMapped] or use the Ignore() method in the modelbuilder.

Both approaches means a rebuild of the assembly is needed and downtime during deployment.

NHibernate's mapping can be done using an XML file and thus all it takes would be a simple config file update.

I can't seem to find anything in EF Core that will reduce the headache of maintaining older codebases when schema changes occur.

Comment: Why do you not remove the property from the model? You obviously doesn't need/want it.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute to `MiddleName`?

Comment: I want to avoid needing to update the c# model or the DbContext if possible since I want to avoid a rebuild of the assemblies.

Comment: You have to either `[NotMapped]` or `.Ignore()`, otherwise EF Core will try to generate sql. Though you *could* build some kind of configurable process to ignore individual columns during `OnModelCreating`. The bigger question is why? The schema is the schema, you shouldn't have to support a broken database. Though I guess you could define computed columns to pretend that the old column still exists, you wouldn't be able to update the table any more.

Answer (score 0):

EF creates a data model mapping internally to track the database schema and your code models. By removing the column in your database table, your code model no longer matches the database. Hence, the exception occurs.

Comment: I think the user knows that.  They want a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not be the answer you're looking for, but as far as I know EF Core need consistency between the models and the DB schemas to work.

I can think of 2 things here:

- Maybe you could benefit from using a different ORM (Did you give Dapper a cahnce)
- You might be facing an architectural issue, if there's more than one team working with the same database, and more than one system calling that database, the best way to avoid headaches in the future would be to isolate the data access layer and expose an API that serves all the involved systems.
  That way, if the database changes, you just need to re-build the data access layer, no downtime for your clients.

And finally... in my opinion the ideal solution is a combination of both, create a decoupled data access layer, map things there and expose an API with the models your application needs.